# How to Remove Pivot Table Rows that contain all "0" values

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table using the following query:

```
declare @custnum nvarchar(7) = '   1124'
declare @yr smallint = 2016

SELECT 'Customer Qty Returned' as Description,'RO' as UnitOfMeasure,
       COALESCE(Jan,0)Jan,
       COALESCE(Feb,0)Feb,
       COALESCE(Mar,0)Mar,
       COALESCE(Apr,0)Apr,
       COALESCE(May,0)May,
       COALESCE(Jun,0)Jun,
       COALESCE(Jul,0)Jul,
       COALESCE(Aug,0)Aug,
       COALESCE(Sep,0)Sep,
       COALESCE(Oct,0)Oct,
       COALESCE(Nov,0)Nov,
       COALESCE(Dec,0)Dec
FROM(
       SELECT ri.u_m,
              CASE WHEN ri.return_item = '1' and ri.u_m = 'RO'
                   then ROUND(ri.qty_to_return,0)
              END AS QtyReturned
             ,left(datename(month,r.rma_date),3) AS RetMonth
       FROM rma r
           INNER JOIN rmaitem ri ON r.rma_num = ri.rma_num
       WHERE r.cust_num = @custnum and YEAR(r.rma_date) = @yr 
)
AS R
PIVOT
(
SUM(QtyReturned)
FOR RetMonth
IN (Jan,Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
)AS pvt
```

This is what the table looks like:
[image]

In this particular example, for this particular customer, all values are "0".
My question is how do I hide or prevent rows with all "0" values from my table?
As you can tell, I am a novice and would appreciate any insight on this issue.

Comment: Put in the `Where` clause a statement to add all of the months together and make sure it's greater than 0...((Coalesce(Jan,0)+Coalesce(Feb,0)+...+Coalesce(Dec,0)) > 0)

Comment: is there a date field on rmaitem table?

Comment: No, there is no date field in the rmaitem table but there is one in the rma table.

Comment: I tried adding the statement you suggested but got an error:                                             
       Invalid column name 'Jan', ......'Dec'
I tried adding it to the existing Where clause, is that correct?